# How to make a custom color map in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Earlier on this platform, I posed a question regarding the definition of "coverage count." However, it became apparent that it was more appropriate to ask it on the signal-processing platform. Fortunately, I was able to obtain the correct definition. Additionally, I was able to write a Python code to calculate the coverage count. However, I encountered a minor issue with the colormap, as it did not meet my desired specifications. For clarification, I have provided images depicting what I currently have versus what I want to achieve:

**Piece 1 relative position in the result:**

[image]

**Piece 2 relative position in the result:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

**The coverage count that I get:**

[image]

**Example of a coverage count (for another image) that I want to get (the colormap that I want):**

[image]

In the last image, there is a coverage count displayed on the left. How can I obtain a coverage count similar to that one?

The following code is what I used to obtain the coverage count mentioned in the question:

```
        non_black_pixels = np.any(piece_image != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
        # Increment the corresponding pixels in the coverage_count
        coverage_count[non_black_pixels] += 1
        # Normalize the coverage_count matrix to the full 8-bit grayscale range (0-255)
        normalized_coverage_count = cv2.normalize(coverage_count, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
        # Apply a colormap to the normalized grayscale image
        colorful_coverage_count = cv2.applyColorMap(normalized_coverage_count, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
        # Display the colorful coverage_count image
        cv2.imshow("Colorful Coverage Count", colorful_coverage_count)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: for plots, use matplotlib. it applies a colormap to grayscale 2D data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reviewing my code, I noticed the following line:

`colorful_coverage_count = cv2.applyColorMap(normalized_coverage_count, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)`

This led me to believe that there might be other color maps available, prompting me to conduct a search on Google. It turns out that there are numerous colormaps to choose from, as listed in the [OpenCV Colormaps](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gga9a805d8262bcbe273f16be9ea2055a65a5d4a709cda1130bfa3cc4b4c5ae8f82a) documentation.

As a result, changing the colormap is straightforward. You can do so by modifying the `cv2.COLORMAP_JET` argument in the code line mentioned earlier to the name of the desired colormap.